# Node set-up in an enterprises

Tags: java, node.js, maven

I have just had a quick introduction on Node. I have not worked on it but it looks like my knowledge on Maven helps a bit to make it easy.

Would it be wrong if I say:

1. Node is like a maven central repository where all the dependencies can be found?
2. `package.json` is like pom which lists all the dependencies.
3. In a big enterprises, there would be a local nexus repository for Maven dependencies. How would that be for node `package.json`? Would there be local nexus repositories for node devDependencies as well?

Apart from this, Node provides a run time environment for running JavaScript. I know it's not exactly the same, but just using the analogy to make it easy for me to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my view on your questions:

1. I would say npm and Maven are about managing dependencies, not node.js itself.
2. package.json is to pom.xml as npm is to Maven and JavaScript is to Java.
3. Our enterprise uses Nexus to manage Java, .NET, and node.js dependencies.  There are both central and local repositories.